# In this quicksort code my last element of list i.e. [44] is not arranged in order

Tags: python, quicksort

In this quicksort code my last element of list i.e. [44]  is not arranged in order

```
def quicksort(A,l,r):
        if r-l<=1:``
            return()
        yellow = l+1
        for green in range(l+1,r):
            if A[green] <= A[l]:
                A[green],A[yellow]=A[yellow],A[green]
                yellow+=1   
        A[l],A[yellow-1]=A[yellow-1],A[l] 
        quicksort(A,l,yellow-1)
        quicksort(A,yellow,r)  
    #command line
    arr = [22,11,88,66,55,77,33,44]
    quicksort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
    print(arr)
```

#output
[11,22,33,55,66,77,88,44]

Comment: Looks like the problem is `quicksort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)`, it works if you change it to `quicksort(arr,0,len(arr))`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling quicksort function with one element less than your "arr".

```
quicksort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
```

Last element is being excluded from it. So make it,

```
quicksort(arr,0,len(arr))
```